# one div with a center aligned div and a right positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have a div element (.shop-bar) that is 100% of the screen width, and fixed position. I want two divs inside that; the first (.search-bar) is to be 50% of the parent and center aligned (accomplished), the second (.cart) is to be at the right of the screen (and the parent div) [problem].

HTML:

```
 <div class="search">
  <div class="search-bar">
   <input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Search"><button><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="cart">
   <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.search {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

#searchbox {
  color: #f0a830;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #202020;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.search-bar input {
  width: 90%;
}

.search-bar button {
  background-color: #202020;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 10%;
}

.cart {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

I've tried floating the .cart right, but it moves the .cart to the next line. I've done a display:inline-block and all the variations. The inline-block makes it possible to move it in the position I want, but it is not actually in the div; more like floating on top. How can I get it to be to the right of the parent?

Comment: there is no `.shop-bar` element in your html

Comment: Sorry about that @MichaelCoker. I changed my html after I posting the CSS.

Comment: no worries. did you figure it out? if not, update your html and css so it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use display inline-block inside a container with text-align center.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="rightalign">right content</div>
  <div class="centeralign">center content</div>
</div>

<style>
  .wrapper{ text-align:center; }
  .centeralign, .rightalign { width:200px;height:100px; }
  .centeralign{ display:inline-block;background:#ccf; }
  .rightalign{ float:right;background:#fcc; }
</style>
```

Other solution would be to create a multi-columns layout.

Comment: It works. However, the right-aligned content pushes the centered search bar. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: `.centeralign{ display:inline-block;margin-right:-100px;background:#ccf; }`